# Extracting numbers in different format from a text in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a column A containing text (Job post) in each cell. I want to extract job Salary (which is number like 2000, 20,000, 4.5k etc) into relevant cell D.

I have shared my google sheet which desired and current output column.
here is google sheet [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/157SVReRROHtErmRcWXuBgLg94BMe3LHb1HYgam2dpRQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Currently I am using a custom script which is extracting only numbers for example(3000, 2000, 9000 etc only) range of numbers which i want to extract is in another sheet names " Data Lookup" .

Custom script is below

```
    /** *
    * @customfunction
    */
    
    
    function salary(text, list){
    
      var result = 'Negotiable';
      list = list.flat();
      list.forEach( str => {
        if(text.includes(str)){
          result = str;
          return result;
        }
      });
      return result;
   }
```

I want to extract numbers which contains comma like (20,000, 30,000, 50,000) and numbers more than 9000 (10000, 11000 etc, currently extracting 1000 and 1100 only from such numbers) and other alphanumeric numbers like (4.5 k , 3.5k 9k etc)

How can i achieve this desired result.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will suggest that you do not need a script to accomplish this.

I've added a new sheet ("Erik Help") to your sample spreadsheet. In that sheet, I have placed a single formula in B2:

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",,IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXREPLACE(LOWER(TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A,CHAR(10),""),",",""))),"^[^~]*([^~]{8}aed.*$)","$1"),"\d{4,6}|\d*\.*\d\s*k"),"[\d\.]+")*IF(NOT(ISERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(A2:A),"\d\s*k"))),1000,1),"unspecified")))`

This one formula will produce results for all rows (based on the limited current information in the sheet). It assumes that you want salary listings rounded to one of the numbers in the 'Data Lookup'!A2:A list.

I added into the formula a few extra parts that will assure you don't wind up extracting a number that you didn't mean to extract.

If this formula suits you, you can get rid of your script and simply use the formula. I always recommend using formulas where possible and reserving script use only for those times when it formulas cannot accomplish the same thing. Following this guideline reduces potential problems all around.

Comment: Thanks erik for your quick help, i am also a believer of using formula instead of code. data posted in sheet is dummy data, i want to extract salary which is in number or alphanumeric shape like 4.5k etc, for data it works fine and i tried to applied on my real data , i found it is not extracting many numbers , i added few more post content at the end of erik hep sheet which is not extracting.  i want to extract any number which is greater than 900 till 10000 , with or without comma  and in alphanumeric shape like 1.5k 1.5 k 1.5K 1.5 K etc

Comment: Simple fix. I just added `CHAR(10)&` before the innermost range. I made this update in my post and in the "Erik Help" sheet of your sample spreadsheet.

Comment: thanks Erik for helping in issue , it is working on my 70% real data , can you see i added few more data in the sheet , that is not working like 8.5k 5.5 k etc, or i am missing something,

Comment: Umar, the intention of this forum is to offer a little help to a lot of people. It isn't designed to offer custom, time-intensive solutions developed by experts free of charge. Each person who volunteers their time here has different personal limitations on how much of their time and expertise they are willing to offer. But at some point, it goes beyond "a little help" to "doing real work for free." That said, I was willing to make one more adjustment (see updated formula in my post). Beyond that, you may need to learn REGEX2 yourself or hire someone.

Answer (score 2):

For this particular dataset this function should work:

```
function get_salary(text){
  
  var num = text.split(' ').reverse()
  .find(x => /\d/.test(x))
  .replace(/,/g,'');

  if (/k/i.test(num)) num = parseFloat(num) * 1000;
  
  return num;
}
```

[image]

It takes a last 'word' that contains a number inside, removes all commas, parses it, mutiplies by 1000 if there is a 'k' and returns the result.

But parsing such texts is a tricky task. Basically there is no general simply solution.

**Update**

Here is the updated version of the function:

```
function get_salary(text){
  
  var num = text.split(/\s/).reverse()
  .filter(x => x.replace(/[^0-9^k]/gi,'').length > 2)
  .find(x => /\d/.test(x))
  .replace(/,/g,'');

  if (/k/i.test(num)) num = parseFloat(num) * 1000;
  
  return num;
}
```

It splits the text by `\s` instead of spaces and excludes the 'numbers' with length less than three digits (if there is no `k`).

[image]

But keep in mind -- there will never be a final solution.

Comment: Yuri thanks a lot for your help , it is really working but in some cases it is not working , i have added few more posts at the end of first where it is not extracting like in 12th column instead of 5.5k (5500) it is showing num error , from 13 to 16th cell , it is extracting number of years which is maximum can go upto 50 years and it is not extracting salaries in such cases,  btw thanks for your script